# Scan Local Network - sendARP function and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, future, arp

I'm trying to scan the local network. To do this, I use the **SendARP()** function, but it works slowly (each call takes about 3 seconds). So I decided to use **Future** for asynchronous processing. **launch::async** starts the execution of the function in a separate thread. And it works, but I'd like to know one thing.

As far as I know, the **SendARP()** function is not thread-safe. Can I then use this function in multithreading, and if so, how? I tried to use mutex, but then I lost the effect of **Future** and my program started working slowly again.

```
arp_mutex.lock();
SendARP((IPAddr)destip.S_un.S_addr, 0, mac_address, &mac_address_len);
arp_mutex.unlock();
```

**Additional question:** inside threads, I also use other non-thread-safe functions, for example, **inet_addr()** and **htonl()** and **inet_ntoa()** and **strcpy()**. should I take care of their security too if they work with DIFFERENT DATA? By the way, is the **sprintf()** function thread-safe or not?

*I hope my question and problem are clear. I really hope to understand this topic.*

```
bool get_mac(unsigned char* mac, char dest[32])
{
    struct in_addr destip;
    ULONG mac_address[2];
    ULONG mac_address_len = 6;

    destip.s_addr = inet_addr(dest);

    SendARP((IPAddr)destip.S_un.S_addr, 0, mac_address, &mac_address_len);

    if (!mac_address_len)
        return false;

    BYTE* mac_address_buffer = (BYTE*)&mac_address;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)mac_address_len; i++)
        mac[i] = (char)mac_address_buffer[i];

    return true;
}

string checkAddress(uint32_t uaddress) {

    struct in_addr addr;
    addr.s_addr = htonl(uaddress);

    char ipAddress[16];
    char result[256] = { '\0' };
    unsigned char mac[6] = { '\0' };

    strcpy(ipAddress, inet_ntoa(addr));

    if (get_mac(mac, ipAddress)) {
        sprintf(result, "IP: %s \t MAC-ADDRESS: %.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X\n", ipAddress, mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
    }

    return result;
}


int main() {

    // Some code
    // ............

    // Iterate over IP addresses from any range. for example 192.168.100.1 - 192.168.100.254 /24
    std::future<string> futureArray[FUTURE_ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (uint32_t address = networkMin; address < networkMax; address) {

        int count = 0;
        for (; count < FUTURE_ARRAY_SIZE; count++) {
            if (++address >= networkMax)
                break;

            futureArray[count] = async(launch::async, checkAddress, address);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            cout << futureArray[i].get();
        }
    }

    // Some code
    // ............

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a function being "thread-safe".  Why do you think a function such as `strcpy` is not thread-safe? A function could be considered unsafe if using it from two different threads necessarily leads to a race condition which is undefined behavior in C and C++.  This is not the case for `strcpy`.

Comment: Note: even if a function set a variable with global scope such as `errno`, this doesn't necessarily mean that the function is not thread safe. In this case of `errno` , it has thread local storage, hence does not share its storage with other threads.

Comment: But I do not know how the strcpy function works inside. Maybe the function refers to some common global variables. Then using such a function in multithreading can lead to errors. For example, there are functions that use a static char* buffer inside themselves

Comment: Did I understand correctly that if I use strcpy in threads with completely different data, then there will be no problems? And what about the SendARP function, for example, I read that this function is not thread-safe... I, too, as in the case of strcpy(), use different data for each thread.

Comment: I just want to understand these points, because I think it's important to understand

Comment: Even if you don't know how the C library functions are implemented, the C standard imposes some behavior. For example in the C18 standard: `7.1.4 §5  Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow, library functions shall
prevent data races as follows[...]`. Then you look at the `strcpy` chapter, and you know that it is safe.